# Can't modify/target outer wrapper in a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to directly target the most outer element of a jQuery object.

```
li = '<li id="test"><span id="testspan">0</span></li>';
var e = $(li);

$('#test', e).html("1");       //example 1
$('#testspan', e).text("2");   //example 2
```

*"example 1"* doesn't work, but *"example 2"* does. How can I target the `#test` this way?

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x36L34vs/10/).

Comment: `e.filter('#test').html("1");`

Comment: Why would you use `filter` here? @PranavCBalan

Comment: select element only if it has the `id`

Comment: Ahh yes, nice idea. Was not thinking about this. Good point. Thanks for clarification. @PranavCBalan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `e` already **is** the `#test` element. No further selector is needed. When you execute `$('#test', e)`, jQuery will look on the **inside** of `e` for `#test`. But `#test` is the outer parent, so there is nothing to find on the inside.

```
li = '<li id="test"><span id="testspan">0</span></li>';
var e = $(li);
e.html("1");
```

Think about how you would work with jQuery itself:

```
var e = $("#test");
e.html("1");
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/x36L34vs/12/)**

Comment: Oh, of course, how did I not realize that.. I was working with nested elements inside it and targeding them with classes and tried applying the same to this, where it wasn't necessary. Thanks.